# Magento 2: Mass Delete PHP code not Working

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, delete, massaction

I'm very new to `Magento`, i created a Mass Action for Delete i write this code in `/EC/Downloads/view/adminhtml/ui_component/ec_downloads_items.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <settings>
            <sticky>true</sticky>
        </settings>
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters"/>

        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <action name="delete">
                <settings>
                    <confirm>
                        <message translate="true">Delete selected items?</message>
                        <title translate="true">Delete items</title>
                    </confirm>
                    <url path="*/items/MassDelete"/>
                    <type>delete</type>
                    <label translate="true">Delete</label>
                </settings>
            </action>
        </massaction>
    </listingToolbar>

    <columns name="ec_downloads_items_columns">
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">downloads_id</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>

        <column name="downloads_id">.......</column>

    </columns>
</listing>
```

and this code in `/EC/Downloads/Controller/Adminhtml/Items/MassDelete.php`

```
<?php
namespace EC\Downloads\Controller\Adminhtml\Items;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

/**
 * Class MassDelete
 */
class MassDelete extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $ids = $this->getRequest()->getParam('downloads_id');
        echo $ids;
        exit;

        if (!is_array($ids) || empty($ids)) {
            echo 'Bad';
            exit; 

            $this->messageManager->addError(__('Please select Item.'));
        } else {
            echo 'Good';
            exit; 

            try {
                foreach ($ids as $id) {
                    $emp = $this->_objectManager->get('EC\Downloads\Model\Downloads')->load($id);
                    $emp->delete();
                }
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                    __('A total of %1 record(s) have been deleted.', count($ids))
                );
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('downloads/index/items');
    }
}
```

code in `/EC/Downloads/Model/ResourceModel/Items.php`

```
<?php

namespace EC\Downloads\Model\ResourceModel;
/**
 * Class Items
 * @package EC\Downloads\Model\ResourceModel
 */
class Items extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{
    /**
     *
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('downloads', 'downloads_id');
    }
}
```

When i try to delete more items it's not working, when i try to `echo|exit`, i found that i dosen't go to the delete part coz `ids` is empty.

Comment: Can you please add more code of ui_component xml file?

Comment: @KazimNoorani Updated....

Comment: Please check my answer. Might help you.

Comment: Is it helpful ?

Comment: I can't see the <item> tag name provider and <dataSource> tag process and make the UI component work with this data.

Comment: Was my answer helpful? @SaifZakir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working fine. Try this

> UI component Form

```
    <action name="delete">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>

                <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="router_name/index/massdelete"/>
                <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                    <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Do you want to delete selected row record?</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </action>
```

> Controller

```
<?php
namespace EC\Downloads\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use EC\Downloads\Model\ResourceModel\Post\CollectionFactory;

class MassDelete extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    protected $_filter;
    protected $serviceFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Filter $filter,
        \EC\Downloads\Model\DownloadsFactory $serviceFactory,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
    ) {

        $this->_filter = $filter;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->serviceFactory = $serviceFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $collection = $this->_filter->getCollection($this->collectionFactory->create());
        $collectionSize = $collection->getSize();
        foreach ($collection as $item) 
        {
        $item = $this->serviceFactory->create()->load($item->getDownloadsId());
        $item->delete();
        }

        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('A total of %1 element(s) have been deleted.', $collectionSize));
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('downloads/index/items');
    }   
}
```

**Note: CODE TESTED**

Comment: Getting this error: `Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[42S22]:`
`Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'where clause', query was:` `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM downloads AS main_table WHERE (`` IN('7'))`
`Exception #1 (PDOException): SQLSTATE[42S22]:` `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'where clause'` @ARUNPRABAKARANM

Comment: Yeah I need to add this line in `Model\ResourceModel\Module\Collection.php` ... `protected $_idFieldName = 'downloads_id';`

Comment: Did you get an error till now?

Comment: Yes bro...! no doubt ....  :)

Comment: Bro @ARUNPRABAKARANM please help me out https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/276387/magento-2-custom-js-not-working-when-adding-more-than-1-js

Answer (score 0):

Does your resourceModel collection have a key defined?

```php
namespace Xigen\Data\Model\ResourceModel\Fitment;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_idFieldName = 'fitment_id';

    /**
     * Define resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            \Xigen\Data\Model\Fitment::class,
            \Xigen\Data\Model\ResourceModel\Fitment::class
        );
    }
}
```

Just for reference here is my MassDelete.php

```
namespace Xigen\Data\Controller\Adminhtml\Fitment;

/**
 * Mass-Delete Controller.
 */
class MassDelete extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Xigen_Data::import';

    private $filter;
    private $collectionFactory;

    /**
     * MassDelete constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter $filter
     * @param \Xigen\Data\Model\ResourceModel\Import\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter $filter,
        \Xigen\Data\Model\ResourceModel\Fitment\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Xigen\Data\Model\FitmentFactory $fitmentFactory
    ) {
        $this->filter = $filter;
        $this->fitmentFactory = $fitmentFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    /**
     * Execute action.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException|\Exception
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $ids = $this->getRequest()->getPost('selected');
        if ($ids) {
            $collection = $this->fitmentFactory->create()
                ->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('fitment_id', array('in' => $ids));

            $collectionSize = $collection->getSize();

            $deletedItems = 0;
            foreach ($collection as $item) {
                try {
                    $item->delete();
                    $deletedItems++;
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
                }
            }
            if ($deletedItems != 0) {
                if ($collectionSize != $deletedItems) {
                    $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                        __('Failed to delete %1 fitment item(s).', $collectionSize - $deletedItems)
                    );
                }
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(
                    __('A total of %1 fitment item(s) have been deleted.', $deletedItems)
                );
            }
        }
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
}
```

Comment: Question updated with `RersourceModel` @DominicXigen

Comment: coulden't understand this.... !

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, this is my code of ui_component listing xml file.

```
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sticky" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters"/>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="bannerslider/banner/massDelete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete Slider</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected Banners?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>                
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
    </listingToolbar>
```

And this is massDelete Controller.

```
<?php
namespace A\BannerSlider\Controller\Adminhtml\Banner;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use A\BannerSlider\Model\ResourceModel\Banner\CollectionFactory;

class MassDelete extends Action
{
    protected $filter;

    protected $collectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Filter $filter,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        Context $context
    ) {
        $this->filter            = $filter;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $collection = $this->filter->getCollection($this->collectionFactory->create());

        $delete = 0;
        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $item->delete();
            $delete++;
        }
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('A total of %1 record(s) have been deleted.', $delete));
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);

        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste your MassDelete.php with below one:

```
                    <?php
                    namespace EC\Downloads\Controller\Adminhtml\Items;

                    use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

                    /**
                     * Class MassDelete
                     */
                    class MassDelete extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
                    {
                        /**
                         * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
                         */

                        public function __construct(
                            \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
                            \Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter $filter,
                            \EC\Downloads\Model\ResourceModel\Items\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
                            \EC\Downloads\Model\ItemFactory $itemFactory
                        ) {
                            $this->filter = $filter;
                            $this->itemFactory = $itemFactory;
                            parent::__construct($context);
                        }  

                          public function execute()
                        {
                            $ids = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
                            if ($ids) {
                                $collection = $this->itemFactory->create()
                                    ->getCollection()
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('downloads_id', array('in' => $ids));

                                $collectionSize = $collection->getSize();

                                $deletedItems = 0;
                                foreach ($collection as $item) {
                                    try {
                                        $item->delete();
                                        $deletedItems++;
                                    } catch (\Exception $e) {
                                        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
                                    }
                                }
                                if ($deletedItems != 0) {
                                    if ($collectionSize != $deletedItems) {
                                        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                                            __('Failed to delete %1 fitment item(s).', $collectionSize - $deletedItems)
                                        );
                                    }
                                    $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(
                                        __('A total of %1 fitment item(s) have been deleted.', $deletedItems)
                                    );
                                }
                            }
                            /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
                            $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
                            return $resultRedirect->setPath('downloads/index/items');
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: not working....

Comment: `->addFieldToFilter('downloads_id', array('in' => $ids));` getting error in this line...

Comment: `Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: PDO::quote() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /var/www/html/mg.local/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php on line 296`

Comment: Are you getting $ids?

Comment: yes... like this: id => 1 and 3:
`Zend\Stdlib\Parameters Object
(
    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
        (
            [selected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 3
                )

            [filters] => Array
                (
                    [placeholder] => true
                )

            [namespace] => ec_downloads_items
            [form_key] => TfQNKpKNTlflHLwE
        )

)`